# Policy on posting links to pirated content?

Tags: discussion, policy, copyright

Do we have a policy about users posting links to sites that feature pirated content? Like sites offering "free" copies of my book, [for example?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837590/can-a-fourier-series-converge-absolutely-to-a-non-continuous-function) (see comment at the bottom).

**Edit:** in case you're wondering, the comment I was complaining about has been removed...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Our practice as I see it, is that they get removed if they are brought to our attention. Moreover, SE has  mechanisms in place to handle things like take-down notices; but this is not something with which per-site moderators are involved.

If a user would repeatedly post links to a problematic site (to promote that site) it would be considered as spam and dealt with as such. In most case, this is however not the case.

The specific case you bring up is rather unusual; the comment should be removed for other reasons, too.

Related:

[Requests for electronic versions of books](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/requests-for-electronic-versions-of-books)

[What is the policy regarding mentioning that a book is available to download via BitTorrent](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-the-policy-regarding-mentioning-that-a-book-is-available-to-download-via)

[Sharing non-legit book source on MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/sharing-non-legit-book-source-on-mse)